# Error inserting nullable integers into bigquery using python API

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery

I am trying to use the bigquery python API to insert data into bigquery tables. More specifically the command:

```
errors = client.insert_rows(table, rows[i*BATCH_SIZE:])
```

The column **gas_used** in my table has a datatype INTEGER and is NULLABLE. But I get the following error while inserting rows with null values in **gas_used**.

> [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{u'debugInfo': u'', u'reason': u'invalid',  u'message': u'Cannot convert value  to integer (bad value):', u'location': u'gas_used'}]}]

Here, is the schema of my table:

```
block_number,transaction_hash,type,trace_address,subtraces,transaction_position,from,to,value_wei,start_gas,input,gas_used,contract_address,output,error
```

and, here is the row which throws the error:

```
[('5000001', '0x2cfd7194877466e6adb87222e5876c4babf8bd59de299698fdce7f0a9a232932', 'call', '[]', '0', '11', '0x77cb68e788aa79640b8a613431cdb10d83208d47', '0x4b3ee0ac445d954f8bca68f9538d54e9633890f6', '349950000000000', '0', '0x', '', '', '', 'Out of gas')]
```

**gas_used** column is the fourth last column in the schema.

Comment: So it corresponds with a value of `''`? That doesn't look like a valid integer to me...

Comment: Elliott is right, the value `''` is an empty string, not integer. You'd have to either replace it with a `None` value or a specific 0 (zero).

Comment: @WillianFuks I would like to retain the `Null` nature of the integer and thus cannot use a specific value 0, but using `None` is a good idea. I have updated the answer with a solution that I found.

Answer (score 0):

As [William Fuks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1002277/willian-fuks) mentioned I have to either mention a Null Integer as `None` or `0`. I would prefer to retain the `Null` nature of the Integer so would prefer using `Nonè

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821244/bigquery-streaming-inserts-using-dataflow-with-null-fields?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) post and am now uploading a list of dictionaries while removing the keys which are null.